# Istio authservice oidc fails to exchange authorization code for access token

Tags: authentication, openid, openid-connect, keycloak, istio

We are trying to setup an oidc provider for authZ and authN with istio in our k8s cluster. We followed this example here: [Bookinfo with Authservice Example](https://github.com/istio-ecosystem/authservice/tree/master/bookinfo-example) for the integration.
Below are the details on the setup:

OIDC provider: Keycloak
Grant type: `authorization_code`
Istio version: `1.5`

Authentication flow:

1. On first request, since there is no authentication, `authservice` successfully redirects to Keycloak, where we're able to login successfully.
2. Keycloak then redirects the request to the application on the redirect_uri. The authorization code is present in this uri now.
3. The redirect_uri is intercepted by the authservice again and it detects the url to be the filter url for oidc as defined in [the configmap](https://github.com/istio-ecosystem/authservice/blob/master/bookinfo-example/config/authservice-configmap-template-for-authn.yaml#L29)
4. Now it tries to call keycloak for exchanging the authorization code for the access token.

This is the step where authservice fails and gives the error `IdP connection error`. The log for the request is as follows:

```
Check: processing request ://microservice.url.com/appservice/oauth/callback?state=LeCNEqfwA6EUFGNGLt7JALx8jCWkPxjn7qCELbqkKrk&session_state=18f0e3b0-bee2-44a5-b049-6e349dbeda49&code=ddea1ea6-5616-416d-8291-c00bce6f2e9b.18f0e3b0-bee2-44a5-b049-6e349dbeda49.af7e7c31-fd4b-4a66-9856-25d1ac305d3f with filter chain idp_filter_chain
20/03/2020 17:27:48 [2020-03-20 11:57:48.546] [console] [trace] New
20/03/2020 17:27:48 [2020-03-20 11:57:48.547] [console] [trace] OidcFilter
20/03/2020 17:27:48 [2020-03-20 11:57:48.548] [console] [trace] Process
20/03/2020 17:27:48 [2020-03-20 11:57:48.548] [console] [debug] Call from @10.42.5.53 to @10.42.5.58
20/03/2020 17:27:48 [2020-03-20 11:57:48.549] [console] [trace] MatchesCallbackRequest: checking handler for ://microservice.url.com/appservice/oauth/callback?state=LeCNEqfwA6EUFGNGLt7JALx8jCWkPxjn7qCELbqkKrk&session_state=18f0e3b0-bee2-44a5-b049-6e349dbeda49&code=ddea1ea6-5616-416d-8291-c00bce6f2e9b.18f0e3b0-bee2-44a5-b049-6e349dbeda49.af7e7c31-fd4b-4a66-9856-25d1ac305d3f
20/03/2020 17:27:48 [2020-03-20 11:57:48.549] [console] [trace] RetrieveToken
20/03/2020 17:27:48 [2020-03-20 11:57:48.550] [console] [trace] Post
20/03/2020 17:27:48 [2020-03-20 11:57:48.618] [console] [info] Post: HTTP error encountered: stream truncated
20/03/2020 17:27:48 [2020-03-20 11:57:48.618] [console] [info] RetrieveToken: HTTP error encountered: IdP connection error
20/03/2020 17:27:48 [2020-03-20 11:57:48.618] [console] [trace] Request processing complete
20/03/2020 17:27:48 [2020-03-20 11:57:48.619] [console] [trace] Processing completion and deleting state
```

On further checking the code, I found this error is triggered from here: [Authservice oidc filter - Github](https://github.com/istio-ecosystem/authservice/blob/master/src/filters/oidc/oidc_filter.cc#L516)

To rule out the issues with the configuration, I used [OpenID Debugger](https://oidcdebugger.com/) to manually generate an authorization code and then called the api to exchange it for an api token. I was able to successfully retrieve it, there was no issue with that. But somehow it is failing with authservice.

Could there be something wrong on my end? Has anyone experienced this issue before? Any help appreciated. Let me know if any more details are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been now fixed by the authservice team. The issue here was, as stated by Ryan from authservice:

> The log indicates that the request was successful right up until the end, when the Authservice tried to gracefully shutdown the TLS connection, and the server on the other side did not participate fully in the graceful shutdown.

The fix here was to ignore the truncation errors. The fix has now been merged to master and will be available in the next release. You can build the docker image yourself for a quick fix. More details about the issue and compilation instructions can be found here on [this github issue](https://github.com/istio-ecosystem/authservice/issues/79)